# i want to fill values in two text box as soon as click event is triggered for autocomplete value. can anyone fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cust_name").on("keyup", function() {
        $("table.testtable").remove();
        if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
            ajaxAutoComplete($(this).val(), $(this));
        }
    });
});

function ajaxAutoComplete(value, Obj) { //alert('1'); $.ajax({ url:"autocomplete.php?val="+value, type:"GET", success:function(data){ //alert("data "+JSON.stringify(data));

    if (JSON.parse(data).length > 0) {
        var htmlString = "<table class='testtable' style='position:absolute;overflow:auto;background:white;'>";
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, value) {
            htmlString += "<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
            // alert(index +" "+value);
        });
        htmlString += "</table>";
        $(htmlString).insertAfter(Obj);
    } else {

    }

},
error: function() {
alert("error");
}
});

}
$(document).on('click', 'table.testtable tr td', function(e) {
    $("#cust_name").val($(this).text());
    $("table.testtable").remove();

});
```

Comment: Data showing up when typing something?

Comment: yeah it sure does show up. .but when autocomplete event is triggered it not passing data to specific text box

Answer (score 0):

Does this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bp1w8ym/1/) do what you want? If you click on "CLICK ON ME" below he adds a value to two textboxes.

```
$('table.testtable tr td').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#cust_name").val($(this).text());
    $("#cust_addresss").val($(this).text());
    $("table.testtable").remove();
});
```

Comment: please put this as a comment,not answer

Comment: I would if I had enough Reputation

Answer (score 0):

this is the code  i have used to trigger the autocomplete value to populate two textbox values

```
$(document).on('click','table.testtable tr td',function(e){
           $("#cust_name").val($(this).text());
          var customer_name=$('#cust_name').val();
alert('1');       
    var datastring= "cust_name="+customer_name;
    //alert('datastring');
             $.ajax({
            url:"../html/autocompletepopulate.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:datastring,
            dataType:"json",
            cache:false,
            success:function(data)
            {   
            alert("data "+JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log(data);
                //window.location="login.html";
                for(i=0;i<data.selftck.length;i++)
                {

               $("#cust_ids").val(data.selftck[i].cust_id);
 $("#ticket_ids").val(data.selftck[i].ticket_id);
 }
  //$("#cust_name").append('"+data.selftck[2].customer_name+"');

            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                alert("Network Errorror...");
            }
        });
```

**this is the html part**

```
    <tr>
    <td>Customer Id</td>                                                    <td> <input type="text"id="cust_ids"> 
    <span style="padding-left:5%"><button>Generate New Id</button></span>  </td>
        </tr>                               
        <tr>
            <td>Ticket Id</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="ticket_id"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Customer Name</td>
        <td><input type="text"  id="cust_name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

  <td>Customer Mail ID</td>
  <td><input type="email" id="cust_mailids"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
  <td>Customer address</td> <td>
  <input type="text" id="cust_addresss" style="width:500px;"></td> </tr>     <tr> <td>Contact Number</td> <td>
   <input type="text" id="cust_phonenos"></td> </tr>
========================================================================
```

Comment: Can you post html structure together. Just relevant part.

Comment: does this code `$(this).text()` displayed value correctly using alert or console.log?